# Where does code memory in Harvard architecture refers to?

Tags: memory, embedded, microcontroller, ram, harvard-architecture

Harvard Architecture is a computer architecture with separate bus for code and data memory. Is that architecture referring code memory which is in RAM or ROM (for Micro-controllers). I was confused when the architecture says about code memory. As far as i know for small scale embedded systems code will always be executing from ROM, whereas in Medium scale and Sophisticated Embedded systems Code memory can be transferred to RAM from ROM for faster execution. If that is the case is RAM connected with two buses one for code and other for data memory. Can any one please help me in understanding this.

Comment: For larger systems, code and data often are in the same RAM, and the term "Harvard Architecture" is sometimes used to mean that they are fetched by different pipelines and via different caches. Typically there will be an arbiter to give both subsystems access a single external memory bus. The practical importance of this is that it's not straightforward to use "self-modifying" code (including boot-loaders etc) on those platforms: you'd need a special sequence of cache-flushing operations whenever you want to overwrite code that you intend to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your response Nick.  Von Neumann architecture is the ability to store program instructions in memory along with the data on which those instructions operate. Does this memory refer to RAM or ROM?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to see this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture

The first time I came across this Harvard architecture thing is on PICs, and they do have their RAM and ROM separated on 2 different address space. But it seems like this is not the only way to do it. Having the data & code accessible at the same time is the key. For example, having a single RAM memory space virtually partitioned to store code & data separately, but accessible by the processor at the same time. It's not a pure Harvard architecture system, but close enough.

Comment: and this is how the world generally works.  A true harvard architecture outside academics is not practical you cant have a bootloader, operating system, etc  (because you would have to do data transfers to load the programs into the instruction space, but they are on separate busses). so some docs will say harvard when meaning modified harvard and really shouldnt bother to say anything as it isnt relevant, the bus spec is the bus spec, done.

Answer (score 0):

*Harvard* has almost nothing to do with RAM or ROM - It just says that, in principle, instruction fetches and data read/write is done over separate buses.

That simply implies that at least *some* ROM (bootstrap code) needs to be found on the instruction memory bus - the rest can be RAM. The non-instruction bus can access RAM or ROM as well - ROM could hold constant data.

On "real" implementations like the AVR MCUs, however, the instruction bus addresses Flash ROM, while the non-instruction bus (I'm deliberately not writing "data bus", that's something different) addresses SRAM. You don't even "see" these buses on an AVR - They are purely internal to most of these MCUs.

Answer (score 0):

Harvard Architecture is for the most part an academic exercise.  First you have to ask how do they determine the split to the four busses?  An internal von neumann that splits by address?  many von nuemann implementations if not all split by address and if you draw a bigger box you see many separate busses sometimes data and instruction are joined, sometimes not.

Because you cant use pure harvard for a bootloader or operating system it is really just a mental exercise.  A label like von neumann that folks like to toss about if for no other reason to create confusion.  The real world is somewhere in between.  AMBA/AXI and other busses are labelled modified harvard because they tag the data and instruction transactions as such but share the same busses (there isnt a single bus on a number of these there are separate read address, read data, write address, write data).  the processor has not been the bottleneck in a long time the processor and these busses can be and are idle so you can have room for instruction and data and peripherals on the same set of busses, particularly if you separate read address, read data, write address, write data into separate busses with id tags being used to connect the dots and complete transactions.

as mentioned on wikipedia the closest you are really going to see in the real world is something like a microcontroller.  And when they talk about memory the really just mean address space, what is out there on the other end of the bus can be sram, dram, flash, eeprom, etc or a combination.  On either side, as well as all the peripherals on that bus.  So in a microcontroller the instructions are in flash in this model and the sram is the data and if a pure harvard architecture there is no way to load code to sram and run it there, likewise you cant use the data bus to program the flash either or to buffer up data to be flashed, the rom/flash gets magically loaded by a not shown on hardvard architecture path.  likely a crossover between the I/O bus resources and the instruction bus resources, which begs to be called modified harvard.

for Von Neumann, you have early address decoders that spit the bus into instructions, data, I/O, and sub divisions of those, perhaps the data and instruction stay combined but you dont have a pure single bus from end to end. not practical.

Look at the pictures on wikipedia, understand one has separate busses for things the other is combined.  Pass the test and forget the terms you wont need them after that they are not really relevant.